# Submit button in servlet is not working

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to make a servlet which will get the data from the html page. I am new to java servlets. When I run the servlet it displays the html page but the submit button does nothing. Please help me figure out what step I am missing.

The html file **/WebContent/index.html** is as follows

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #box{
                width: 92%;
                padding: 25px;
                border: 5px solid black;
                margin: 25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "box">
            <form action ="/src/XXXXXX/servletEX" method="post" id = "summary">
                Purchase Order : <input type="text" name="order"><br>
                Invoice : <input type="text" name="invoice"><br>
                Invoice Date : <input type="date" name="date"><br>
                Supplier Tax ID : <input type="text" name="taxid"><br>
                <p>Remit to : </p>
                <p>Bill to :</p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id = "box">
            <form action = "/src/XXXXXX/servletEX" method ="post" id = "tax">
                SHIPPING  <input type="checkbox"  value="head"> Header Level Shipping
                <input type="checkbox"  value="line" checked> Line Level Shipping <br>
                <span>Ship from _____________________</span>
                <span>Ship to  _______________________</span>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id = "box">
            <h4>Additional Field Only</h4>
            <form action = "/src/XXXXXX/servletEX" method="post" id = "additional">
                <input type="checkbox"  value="head"> information only, No action required from customers </br>
                <span> Supplier Account ID: <input type="text" name="order"> </span> 
                <span> Service Start Date : <input type="date" name="date"></span><br>
                <span> Customer refrence : <input type="text" name="order"> </span> 
                <span> Service End Date : <input type="date" name="date"></span>
                Payment Note : <input type="text" name="order"></br>
                <span>Supplier ____________________</span>
                <span>Customer ____________________</span><br>
                Email : <input type="text" name="order"></br>
                Bill from : <input type="text" name="order"></br>
                <h4> SUPPLIER VAT</h4>
                Supplier VAT/Tax ID : <input type="text" name="order"></br>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" >
            <input type="reset" name="reset" >

         </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The xml file **/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml** is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletEX</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>XXXXXX.servletEX</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletEX</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletEX</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

..and following is the servlet code **/JavaResources/src/(package)/servletEX.java**

```
package XXXXXXX;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream;




public class servletEX extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public servletEX() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet Parameter</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        Enumeration parameters = request.getParameterNames();
        String param=null;

            System.out.println ("Its here") ;
            while (parameters.hasMoreElements())
            {

                  param=(String)parameters.nextElement();                  
                  System.out.println (param + " " + request.getParameter(param));
                  out.println(param + ":" + request.getParameter(param) + "<br>" );                  
            }
       out.println("</body></html>");

       out.close();
    }



}
```

Comment: put your submit button inside the _<form>_ tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit button should be inside  tag,

```
   <form action = "/src/XXXXXX/servletEX" method="post" id = "additional">
            <input type="checkbox"  value="head"> information only, No action required from customers </br>
            <span> Supplier Account ID: <input type="text" name="order"> </span> 
            <span> Service Start Date : <input type="date" name="date"></span><br>
            <span> Customer refrence : <input type="text" name="order"> </span> 
            <span> Service End Date : <input type="date" name="date"></span>
            Payment Note : <input type="text" name="order"></br>
            <span>Supplier ____________________</span>
            <span>Customer ____________________</span><br>
            Email : <input type="text" name="order"></br>
            Bill from : <input type="text" name="order"></br>
            <h4> SUPPLIER VAT</h4>
            Supplier VAT/Tax ID : <input type="text" name="order"></br>


         <input type="submit" name="submit" >
        <input type="reset" name="reset" >

        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the submit buttons are outside of forms

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" >
<input type="reset" name="reset" >
```

As far as I know, ***In current scenario you cannot submit forms without using javascript***. or place ***submit buttons inside of forms***.

Answer (score 0):

Form gets submitted, if it sees the submit button within it. It the button is out of the scope of `<form> </form>` tag, it won't submit it.

You need to place them inside the form tags

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" >
<input type="reset" name="reset" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a submit button inside the form or - in HTML5 - set the form id in the button:

```
<button type="submit" form="additional">Go</button>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Button

Answer (score 0):

Put your submit button inside `<form></form>` tag. And also **remove multiple forms** from your page and include all field in single form tag as all your forms have same action.